# can we return variable from the python decoretor?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, python-decorators, django-sessions, django-1.8

I have used function for checking session key in django (it need to code).

```
def sessioncheck(unikey):
   from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
   try:
       session_obj = Session.objects.get(pk=unikey)
       userinfo = session_obj.get_decoded()
       # Here i want some data to return 
       userkey = userinfo["session_datakey"] 
       username = userinfo["session_user"] 
       return userkey,username # i need it in my function and as many other stuff to with it
   except(ObjectDoesNotExist, KeyError):
       response = JsonResponse({"expire": "u r not here anymore"})
       return response
```

Here I like to use it as decorator? but not getting it how can be done i.e return part for the **userkey** 
The above function i like to use as decorector.

```
# Currunt i m using as
def sessioncall(request, unikey):
      gotukey,username = sessioncheck(unikey)
      if type(token).__name__ is not "JsonResponse":
           # Lots of work using **gotukey** and **username** over here 
           # work change from function to function for use gotukey
           response = JsonResponse({"hmm": "man you are in now"})
           return response
      else:
           return gotukey
```

I know we can use *decorator* to raise error but i also want to *return* some values if it *success*.
**my question is can we write decorator? or we need to use at function call only for return**

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you could use a function to create a decorator, also known as [decorators with arguments](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845). Then just wrap the original function to work like you want, with the value you'd normally return.

Comment: i have added some code how exact scenario i like to use 
**sessioncall** is function where i like to use **sessioncheck** as _decorator_.

Comment: Is that the *exact* code you're using? Seems like you don't need the `username` for anything, and you're using `gotukey` only for return value? **Edit:** Also, why do you want decorators in the first place? What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: some scenario i use _username_ some i won't . As i m using this function for every request made by client the code check session in db with **unikey** on server side. and return some data i process on that.
my question was can we use it as decorator? i would realy like it to have . it give some cleanness in code .